# How to delete heap allocated variable after function returns

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

I just wanted to know how one would go about, or if there is even a need to, `delete []` an array declared like this:

```
int* arrgen(int x)
{
    int *newarray = new int[x];
    return newarray;
}
```

How would you go about deleting the `newarray` after the function returns? Or does it "auto" `delete` after the function returns along with the rest of the variable native to the function?

Comment: If there is a `new []`, there better be a `delete []` **somewhere**. You don't have one here, so someone caller-side had better `delete [] res;` on the resulting pointer returned. That said, use a smart pointer and this becomes a non-issue. Or better still. `std::vector<int>`

Comment: by changing the design of your program. just don't do return allocated stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you would have to delete from outside the function in this case. Anyway, if you deleted from inside the function, you would have a dangling pointer when returning, so it makes no sense.

If you want automatic deallocation, do this, making use of c++11:

```
std::unique_ptr<int []> newarray(new int[x]);
return newarray;
```

This will return `newarray` and when you stop using it, it will call `delete []` through the `unique_ptr` destructor.

Comment: Thanks to everyone commenting and answering. This one is precisely what i was looking for! Thanks Germán Diago!

Answer (score 0):

C++ gives you control of memory management (unlike garbage-collected languages like C# or Java which look after it for you).  So, you can allocate memory with new (new[] for arrays) and de-allocate with delete (delete[] for arrays) as and when you see fit.

This can be more of a curse than a blessing - there are many ways it can go wrong.  If you call 'delete' twice for the same address, you get undefined behaviour (e.g. program crash).  If you allocate memory with new but fail to delete it, then you have a 'memory leak' - as your program runs it will grow and grow in memory usage.

To avoid these problems, you really need a strategy for managing memory.  For every piece of memory that is allocated, it should be clear from your strategy which code 'owns' the memory and is responsible for deleting it.  Two common strategies are [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) and [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization#C.2B.2B_example).

Your original code doesn't seem to have a strategy for ownership which means it could be dangerous.  The code calling your function needs to assume ownership of the returned pointer and must be careful to delete it - possibly in lots of different places if your function is used widely.  This explains why someone comments "just dont return allocated stuff", and why Germán suggests using a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make newarray static like this:

```
int* arrgen(int x) {
  static int *newarray = new int[x];
  return newarray;
}
```

This way the array doesn't get erased from the stack after exiting the function. Then inside main() you could do something like this:

```
int* vector = arrgen(n);
...
delete [] vector;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would you go about deleting the newarray after the function returns?

You wouldn't. Deleteing the new array when the function returns means to return an invalid reference/pointer to the array.

What you want is to use an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> arrgen(int x) {
    std::vector<int> newarray(x);
    return newarray;
}
```

and return it (thanks to RVO you don't pay for any copy at all).

But hey, that's just the constructor of `std::vector`. So you don't even need to create a function for that:

```
std::vector<int> newarray(x);
```